# How to reverse the group comparison order for t.test()?

Tags: r, t-test

I would like to conduct a two-sample independent t-test and my grouping variable, "group" is factored as '0' and '1'. When calling the `t.test()`, it calculates the difference as mean for group 0 - mean for group 1, giving me a negative difference and negative confidence intervals.

How can I reverse the order of comparison so that R estimates mean for group 1 - mean for group 0? I know it compares [alphabetically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49839126/two-sample-t-test-in-r-direction-of-comparison), so I assume it compares numbers in increasing value. I already tried `fct_rev()` from the `forcats` package to set group '1' as the reference group, but that did not change the order in which `t.test` compared and still gave negative outputs. This is important as it is a 1 sided test so I have expectations on the sign of the difference.

Thanks!

EDIT: I'd like to keep the names as '0' and '1' because they need to be coded as such for subsequent analyses to work

Comment: 1 - group will work so it if group is numeric.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `levels` argument when constructing the factor. It is possible to revert the levels (see code below) and it is also possible to specify an arbitrary order:

```r
# two samples with different mean
x <- c(rnorm(10, 5, 1), rnorm(10, 8, 1))

# the grouping variable
f1 <- factor(rep(0:1, each=10))

# the grouping variable with reverse order of levels
f2 <- factor(f1, levels=rev(levels(f1)))

t.test(x ~ f1)

t.test(x ~ f2)
```

Comment: Thanks! I was aiming for this with `fct_rev()` (which didn't work initially) but your proof made me try it from another way. Previously, I tried to reverse the levels before a series of subsets and reshaping, but now I moved the reverse levels further down, a version of this:  `shapeddf <- df %>% gather (....) %>% gather(...) %>% mutate( group = fct_rev(as.factor(group)) )` made the t-tests compare in the order I wanted

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I cannot comment, can you not simply recode your variables and rerun it so they run in the correct order?
e.g.:

```
mydata <- read.csv(yourdataset.csv, na.strings = "")
#make a new "recoded group" variable
mydata$group.recoded <- mydata$group
mydata <- within(mydata, group.recoded[group.variable==group0] <- "group2")
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have edited my post to reflect that I want to keep the names, but I've since found a fix